# Precisely when is the version field updated on a versioned JPA entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

I would like to know precisely when the field annotated with `@Version` is effectively incremented (and accessible with its incremented value) on the entity among the following processings :

- `entitymanager.flush()` (triggered or not by commit)
- before *or* after a `@PreUpdate` annotated callback method
- before *or* after a `@PostUpdate` annotated callback method

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the code that is executed during update in `org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction#execute`. The version in the object is updated after `@PreUpdate` and before `@PostUpdate` are called.